# How can I test css properties? My test always passes

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

My app is slightly unusual in that the appearance is actually critically important. It's sort of a photo manipulation app, so I want to be able to write tests to check, for example, that an element actually has a particular background color. I'm able to find elements with `react-testing-library` but my jest `.toHaveStyle()` assertions seem to always pass.

**The element under test (rest of component omitted)**

```
      <span
        className="swatch"
        style={{ background: `#${colorToString(color)}` }}
        aria-label="original color"
      />
```

**The test**

```
describe('BeadMapRow', () => {
  let result: RenderResult;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const bead = {
      brand: 'Test',
      code: 'T01',
      name: 'Test Bead 1',
      color: 0x005080ff
    };
    result = render(<BeadMapRow color={0x084a8bff} bead={bead} />);
  });

  it('works', () => {
    const e = result.getByLabelText('original color');
    console.log(e);
    expect(e).toHaveStyle({ 'background-color': '0x084a8bff' });
  });
});
```

**Result of that `console.log` (trimmed)**

```
console.log src/components/beadMapRow.test.tsx:21
      HTMLSpanElement {
        '__reactInternalInstance$a7if3tsd8xg':
         FiberNode {
           tag: 5,
           key: null,
           elementType: 'span',
           type: 'span',
           stateNode: [Circular],
           return:
            FiberNode {
               /* ... */
               },
           child: null,
           sibling:
            FiberNode {
              /*...*/
               },
           index: 0,
           ref: null,
           pendingProps:
            { className: 'swatch',
              style: [Object],
              'aria-label': 'original color' },
           memoizedProps:
            { className: 'swatch',
              style: [Object],
              'aria-label': 'original color' },
           /* ... */
        '__reactEventHandlers$a7if3tsd8xg':
         { className: 'swatch',
           style: { background: '#084a8bff' },
           'aria-label': 'original color' },
        [Symbol(SameObject caches)]:
         [Object: null prototype] {
           style:
            CSSStyleDeclaration {
              _values: {},
              _importants: {},
              _length: 0,
              _onChange: [Function] },
           childNodes: NodeList {} } }
```

If I change the expected color to something else, it still passes. The only way so far I've found to make it fail is to say `.toHaveStyle('background-color')` without a value.

Comment: Why don't you check `expect(e).toHaveStyle({ 'background-color': '#hex' });` with `hex` value ? Also, to make sure you do not confuse `react-testing-library` maybe you should use `background-color` in the style you pass to the `span` tag.

Comment: Even testing `background` instead of `background-color`, and using `#hex` instead of `0x###` it still always passes with wrong color values.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a codesanbox ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that issue is with the name of the property used to compare the color  in the expect, in the component you used the propety background not backgroud-color so  try
`expect(e).toHaveStyle({ 'background': '#0x084a8bff' });`
instead of
`expect(e).toHaveStyle({ 'background-color': '0x084a8bff' });`

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

`.toHaveStyle()` works as intended when you pass colour value types different from the one you are passing, as you can see [in this Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-tree-8kmcn?file=/src/beadMapRow.test.js). So it must be something with how you are formatting you colour values.

Comment: Thanks, I think one of my problems was I need to test using a string instead of an integer. However there's still an issue - try adding alpha values by adding `ff` to the end of all the colors in the test file, both in props and in the assertion. When you do that they both pass. So it seems like something here doesn't support alpha.

Comment: It looks like if I use `rgba()` in the style, and also test with that style including the alpha, then it will work. `toHaveStyle` seems to be unable to handle alpha in the hex values.